# Algorithm to find the union of multiple strings grouped by character index

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, optimization, union

I have been trying to think of a performance efficient way of finding the union of character occurrences in a set of `fixed width` strings grouped by index. Something like this;

```
s1 = "013965"
s2 = "015935"
s3 = "310012"
```

Resulting in the following where each group of digits exists in all strings at char index n:

```
out = "[03][1][350][90][631][52]"
```

I have thought of doing it the very naive way of iterating through every string, at every index while storing the intermediate strings in an array and then iterating through that array to build the output value. However my approach seems to me as a highly inefficient way  which is way too far from an asymptotically optimal solution.

Comment: Usually it's best to just get things functionally correct, then worry about performance after you've got a working solution. While doing things the naive way often help you see places where gains can easily be made.

Comment: Google 'profile matrix bioinformatics'. Might give you a few ideas.

Comment: I think you cannot do much better than the naive way because normally you need to go through all positions of all strings (unless at position k all digits 0-9 have already occurred). Imagine all your strings start with 4 and the last one starts with 5, then you need to go through all strings' 0-positions in order not to miss the last string's 5 (which is different at that position than all the others). The same applies for each position.

Comment: @MagicMan, peter.petrov: Thanks for the comments and suggestions, however my need for thoughts on optimizations are crucial as the algorithm will execute against 120,000 strings of length ~10.

Comment: Can you prepare the data in any way or are you just given a set of 120,000 fixed-width strings you've never seen before?

Comment: @groovy, never seen before. One of the optimizations that just occurred to me is to stop processing an index should all the 0-9 characters have been detected already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the set of all possible characters is known in advance, let's say their number is `n`, with `n` being not too high (e.g. 10, if you're doing only digits), you can do this by creating `m` boolean arrays of length `n`, with `m` being the number of positions, or digits in input strings and `n`. The n-th position in m-th array will be `true`, if the n-th character is present in m-th position in any of input strings. `False` will denote, that no such character was in m-th position before.

Then you can iterate over each string, and when you encounter character `n` in position `m` you mark down `true` in n-th position of m-th array. At the end, you will have `m` arrays, each describing the content of m-th group

```
pos[0] = {true, true, false, false, false, true, true, false, true, false}
pos[1] = {true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false}
pos[2] = {false, false, true, true, false, false, false, false, false, true}
```

translates to

```
[0,1,5,6,8] [0] [2,3,9]
```

As all the structures are direct access arrays, there is no lookup involved, all access is in constant time and you only need to visit every character once, with no comparison involved. Hope this helps.

Comment: the second group should be [0] and the third [2,3,9] according to the data translations done in the first group